# Model relationship with itself Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I have a table of Lessons.  I want some Lessons to be prerequisites to other lessons.  I call these lessons Goal and Prerequisite.  I have made a Prerequisite model and Prerequisites table as below.
I can retrieve Lesson->prerequisite using oneToMany in the Lesson model.
I want to make the Prerequisite->Lesson relationship but can't work out the syntax for making this relationship in the Prerequisites model.

Here are my migrations:

```
Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('course_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('blurb');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('YouTube');
        $table->integer('order_in_course');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

Schema::create('prerequisites', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreignID('goal');
        $table->foreignID('prerequisite');
        $table->foreignID('status_id');
        $table->integer('status_repetitions_required');
        $table->integer('spacing_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Here's the lesson model:

```
public function prerequisites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prerequisite::class, 'goal');
}
```

and the Prerequisite model:

```
public function lesson()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Lesson::class, 'prerequisite');
}
```

And here's the test I'm running:

```
    /**
* prerequisite_to_lesson_relationship
* @test
*/
public function prerequisite_to_lesson_relationship()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    /** make lessons and prerequisite */
    $goal = Lesson::factory
    ( [ 'title' => 'Goal Lesson' ,] ) -> create();
    $prerequisite = Lesson::factory
    ( [ 'title' => 'Prerequisite Lesson', ] )->create();
    $this->seed(PrerequisiteSeeder::class);

    /** now get the lesson from the  prerequisite using controller method getLessonFromPrerequisite*/
    $lessonFromPrerequisite = $prerequisite->lesson;

    dd($lessonFromPrerequisite);
}
```

When I run the test the dd() returns 'null'.

I have tried to write the belongsTo in the Prerequisite model but nothing seems to work.  The problem seems to be around not using standard foreign keys (which didn't work because you can't repeat lesson_id as a column name in Prerequisites table).
Anyone know how to write the relationship to get Lesson from Prerequisite??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foreignID` is a alias of `$table->unsignedBigInteger('goal');` and `constrained` method will use convention to determine the table and column name being referenced, so it should be somethink like  `$table->unsignedBigInteger('goal')->constrained();`
  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: You don't have a primary key column on your prerequisites table.

Comment: Nobody's going to look at your database column names, so don't try to get fancy. Stick with `id`, `lesson_id`, etc.